# extjs gridpanel reconfigure issue

Tags: extjs, gridpanel

I have the below to reconfigure `gridpanel`, it works fine the first time, but the second time it throws the following error:

> JavaScript runtime error: unable to get property 'id' of undefined or null reference"

What is wrong with my code?

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Create",
        data: JSON.stringify({ inputdata: selectedValues }),
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {

                var columns = [];
                var _fields = [];
                var data = {
                    Key: [],
                    Value: []
                };

                var nameCount = 0;
                var resultSet = result.result;
                resultSet.forEach(function (element) {
                    for (var key in element) {
                        if (element.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            var keyStr = key;


                                    data.Key.push(keyStr);
                                    data.Value.push(element[key]);


                            }
                        }
                    }

                });

                var column;

                var count = 0;
                resultSet.forEach(function (element, index, ar) {

                    for (var key in element) {
                        if (!element.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
                        if (element.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            var field = {};
                            var elementValue = element[key];
                            var typeCheck = typeof elementValue;

                            field['name'] = key;
                            if (key.startsWith('Completed')) {
                                field['type'] = 'date';
                                field['submitFormat'] = 'm/d/Y';
                                field['submitValue'] = true;
                            }
                            else {
                                switch (typeCheck) {
                                    case 'number':
                                        field['type'] = 'int';
                                        break;
                                    case 'boolean':
                                        field['type'] = 'string';
                                        break;
                                    case 'string':
                                        field['type'] = 'string';
                                        break;
                                    case 'object':
                                        field['type'] = 'object';
                                        break;
                                    case 'date':
                                        field['type'] = 'date';
                                        break;
                                    default:

                                }
                            }

                            _fields.push(field);
                            if (key == 'EmployeeId' || key == 'EmployeeGroup'
                                || key == 'GroupMemberId') {
                                column = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', {
                                    text: key,
                                    dataIndex: key,
                                    hidden: true
                                });
                                columns.push(column);
                            }
                            else {
                                if (!key.startsWith('EmployeeName') && !key.startsWith('EmployeeStatus') && !key.startsWith('Completed')) {
                                    column = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', {
                                        text: key,
                                        dataIndex: key,
                                        width: 80
                                    });
                                    columns.push(column);

                                }

                            }

                        }
                    }
                });

                        var keyValue = data.Key;
                        var values = data.Value;
                        var nameKeyValue = [];
                        var nameFinalValue;
                        for (var i = 0; i < keyValue.length; i++) {
                            for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
                                if (keyValue[i].startsWith('Name')) {
                                    nameKeyValue.push(values[j]);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        for (var i = 0; i < keyValue.length; i++) {
                            nameFinalValue = nameKeyValue[i];

                                if (keyValue[i].startsWith('Name')) {

                                    var status = keyValue[i + 1];
                                    var completed = keyValue[i + 2];
                                    column = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', {
                                        text: nameFinalValue,
                                        dataIndex: nameFinalValue,
                                        columns: [
                                            Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', {
                                                text: 'Employee Status',
                                                dataIndex: status,
                                                width: 80,
                                                stopSelection: false,
                                                editable: true,
                                                editor: {
                                                    xtype: 'checkbox'
                                                },
                                                field: { xtype: 'checkbox' }
                                            }),
                                            Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', {
                                                text: 'Completed',
                                                dataIndex: completedOn,
                                                width: 80,
                                                editor: new Ext.form.DateField({
                                                    xtype: 'datefield',
                                                    format: 'm/d/y',
                                                    renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y')
                                                })
                                            })
                                        ]
                                    });
                                    columns.push(column);
                                }


                        }


                // *** new code
                var store = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
                    id: 'myStore',
                    fields: _fields,
                    groupField: 'Group',
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'ajax',
                        reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            root: 'data'
                        }
                    }
                });
                var grid = App.myGrid;

                grid.reconfigure(Ext.getStore('myStore'), columns);//this line throws error
                grid.getStore().loadData(result.result);
                grid.getView().refresh();

                selectedValues = [];

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: please post a complete text of your error

Answer (score 0):

replace error-throwing line with
grid.reconfigure(store, columns);

Comment: thanks for your response, but I have already tried this with no luck

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer, e.g. provide a code sample and explain why your suggestion should work

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your store before loading new data

```
grid.getStore().removeAll();
```

Comment: By the way, why is it necessary to invoke `loadData` after `reconfigure`?

Comment: grid.getStore.removeAll() doesn't solve the problem (error is still there). also, I am using loadData to load the data after reconfiguring the gridpanel structure with new store and columns.